# What does a adult cat want when it meows a lot?

Tags: cats, health, vocalizations

I have fed him today and played with him. He still meows randomly I just wanna know why he is meowing a lot.

Comment: you need to give more information about the cat,age,gender,the general situation when the cat meows.there is a lot of different reasons for why a cat gets vocal so more information will help getting you an answer.

Comment: We need to know a lill bit more details and the context of his meowing, please include them. But until then, simply said, the cat certainly wants your attention!

Comment: In your list of possible needs, consider water.  Cats don't often drink much, but a diabetic cat will drink much mire.